# Splitting Aggregated counts into rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have date like this

```
CustId  Frequency  Date
------  ---------  -----
C1        2        20-Jan-2015
C2        3        22-Feb-2015
```

I have to get the output like below

```
C1  20-Jan-2015
C1  20-Jan-2015
C2  22-Feb-2015
C2  22-Feb-2015
C2  22-Feb-2015
```

Can anyone please help me with this query.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated hierarchical query to generate extra rows (without having to create an extra table and ensure that your frequencies do not exceed the match the range of those numbers):

```
SELECT CustID,
       "Date"
FROM   CustomerFrequencies c,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= c.Frequency
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick answer. It's working fine

Answer (score 2):

You need a numbers table.  There are various ways to generate one.  Here is an explicit method:

```
with numbers(n) as (
      select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3 from dual
     )
select d.CustId, d.date + n.n - 1 as date
from data d join
     numbers n
     on d.frequency <= n.n;
```

If you want to generate a bunch of numbers, a typical method is:

```
with numbers(n) as (
      select level as n
      from dual
      connect by level <= 365
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have a number table and join with it

```
select t1.CustId,t1.Date+t2.number as date 
from table t1 inner join numbers t2
on t2.number<=t1.frequency
```

Comment: Hi Madhivanan, I am executing this query in Oracle and getting an error "ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier". Is DATEADD any specific function which is not available in Oracle?

Comment: Oracle? Then you can just add it. See my edited reply

Comment: Thanks for the clarification